# where to download the dotnet-dev-win-x86.1.0.0-preview 2-1-003180

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

when open the visual Studio than report an error, image attached for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download it from below links.

1. [dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0-preview 2-1-003180](https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/preview/Installers/1.0.0-preview2-1-003180/dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0-preview2-1-003180.exe)
2. [dotnet-dev-win-x86.1.0.0-preview 2-1-003180](https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/preview/Installers/1.0.0-preview2-1-003180/dotnet-dev-win-x86.1.0.0-preview2-1-003180.exe)

Comment: Thanks,It is very useful to me